# Is there any way to know if Windows 7 Touch is active on the device?

Tags: windows-7, touch

When we go to Control Panel -> System, the detail shows a number of details like windows experience index including "Pen and Touch: Pen and Touch Input Available with x Touch Points".

Is there any way to know this information from .NET/C# application? Basically I want to know whether the application can use touch/gestures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can call GetSystemMetrics you can find this information. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371581%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shows how to do it. Test for the multi-input and stack-ready bits.

I know you're asking about C#, but in C you use:

```
int value = GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER);
if (value & NID_READY) { /* stack ready */}
    if (value & NID_MULTI_INPUT) {
        /* digitizer is multitouch */ 
    }
}
```